# Setup a Trigger on Table to limit the number of INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE Operations

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssms, dml

**For example**: A user should not be able to perform `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations more than *X* number of times on a particular table at a given point of time, if the user performs an operation *X*+1 times than a trigger will be launched.

Comment: That isn't how a `TRIGGER` works. A `TRIGGER` "fires" every time the DML that the trigger is related to is run against the object the `TRIGGER` belongs to. But this smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to stop a user performing say 20 `INSERT` statements (that effect 1 row each) within a second, but allow them to process 3 that effect 10,000 each? Or are you purely trying to stop people using RBAR operations? If so, teach them how to write set-based SQL.

Comment: The aim of achieving this scenario is to limit the number of records a user query can modify within a table. This is to avoid mass updates to a table by mistake or intentionally. For example user will not be able to run mass UPDATE query or DELETE query for a particular table

Comment: Honestly, this seems more like staff should be checking their work before they (stupidly) writing a statement like `UPDATE YourTable SET IsActive = 0 WHERE IsActive = 1;`. What does that have to do with an `INSERT `though?

Comment: This sounds like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: We can all admit (even those of us that are experienced) that we do sometimes runs queries like that, however, that's why Dev and staging environments, and replacing `UPDATE` with a `SELECT` first is so important; so that you know what you're updating/deleting.

Comment: I understood what are you trying to convey this scenario will not be achieved with the help of triggers, is there any other possibility to achieve the above scenario that is to avoid bulk insert, update, delete operations at single amount of time on a particular table.

Comment: `BULK INSERT` is quite different to an `INSERT`, and there's not such thing as a `BULK UPDATE` and `BULK DELETE`. If you want to stop people performing a `BULK INSERT` just don't give them the Bulk operations permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table dbo.targetTable
(
    id int,
    colA varchar(10)
);
go
create or alter trigger dbo.DMLxTimes on dbo.targetTable
for insert, update, delete
as
begin
    /*
        --old days..
        IF @@ROWCOUNT > 5
        begin
            rollback;
        end
    --*/

    declare @maxrows int = 5; --maximum number of rows allowed per dml action

    if 
    (select count(*) from inserted) > @maxrows
    or
    (select count(*) from deleted) > @maxrows
    begin
        rollback;
    end
end
go

insert into dbo.targetTable(id, colA)
values (0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'); --5 rows inserted
go
insert into dbo.targetTable(id, colA)
values (0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'); --6 rows inserted ... error
go
insert into dbo.targetTable(id, colA)
values (0, 'a'),(0, 'a'); --2 rows inserted
go

--all updated, error
update dbo.targetTable
set colA = colA;
go

--ok
update top(5) dbo.targetTable
set colA = colA;
go

delete top (4) from dbo.targetTable;
go

--ok
update top(15) dbo.targetTable
set colA = colA;
go
```

Comment: I would, personally, suggest using `THROW` not `ROLLBACK` in the trigger. Handling of transactions should be done outside the trigger, and you can also pass a helpful error.