# Limit the insertion/deletion using a threshold value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use a trigger on a table to prevent insertion, updating or deletion of any  table entries after count > 2. Basically I want to prevent the use of bulk operations. Please can anyone help me? Can we use try catch for this?
Please find the below command for trigger creation:

```
create  trigger [dbo].[DMLxTimes] on [dbo].[targetTable]
for insert, update, delete
as
begin

declare @maxrows int = 5; --maximum number of rows allowed per dml action

if 
(select count(*) from inserted) > @maxrows
or
(select count(*) from deleted) > @maxrows

begin
        THROW 50005, N'This statement cannot be executed', 1;
end
end
GO
```

Below are the queries tried :

```
insert into dbo.targetTable(id, colA)
values (0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'); --5 rows inserted
go

insert into dbo.targetTable(id, colA)
values (0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'),(0, 'a'); --6 rows 
inserted ... error
go

insert into dbo.targetTable(id, colA)
values (0, 'a'),(0, 'a'); --2 rows inserted
go

--all updated, error
update dbo.targetTable
set colA = colA;
go

--ok
update top(5) dbo.targetTable
set colA = colA;
go

delete top (4) from dbo.targetTable;
go

--ok
update top(15) dbo.targetTable
set colA = colA;
go
```

This above queries give the expected output for insert query every single time but for different scenario like when count is changing at that time for updation and deletion the query sometimes give the output and sometimes for the same query doesnt work in the same manner.eg when update top(14),update top (20),etc.

Comment: No, you would not use `try`/`catch` for this.  You would use a trigger.

Comment: In your trigger count the entries in the [`inserted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) table

Comment: Okay.Thank you ,Gordon Linoff. But how do I prevent bulk updation or deletion of data entry into the table by setting up a threshold suppose 2 using a trigger.

Comment: @DaleK, Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: `if (select count(*) from Inserted) > 1 rollback;`

Comment: Thank you @DaleK... You are trying to say what exactly is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60375515/11990922...I have tried that but it is working sometimes and sometimes with the same script it is not considering the conditions. I am searching for something more high level script ..

Comment: 1) If you have tried something already then please show us what you have tried so that we don't waste our time telling you what you already know. 2) If its not working tell us how to reproduce the problem so we can help solve it. 3) What on earth does a "more high level script" even mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60375515/11990922   I have used this link and exactly the same steps I have performed which are specified in this link.But It is not giving me the output for update top(15) or delete top(10) correctly sometimes ...I am not able to explain more than this ...please if you can help me with some other logic it would be great!

Comment: That code and logic works... and is the cleanest way to do this. We can't help you unless you post your exact code, and your exact test data, because something you are doing must be different to that example for it not to be working for you. On SO you always need a [MRE] because otherwise we cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have made the changes @DaleK please go through the question again..

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry for the confusion ...the query in the question perfectly works for my scenario.

```
create  trigger [dbo].[DMLxTimes] on [dbo].[targetTable]
for insert, update, delete
as
begin

declare @maxrows int = 2; --maximum number of rows allowed per dml action

if 
(select count(*) from inserted) > @maxrows
or
(select count(*) from deleted) > @maxrows

begin
        THROW 50005, N'This statement cannot be executed', 1;
end
end
GO
```

This is perfect for my scenario.